# set random images to imageview android

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview

I thought to make an array of Bitmaps and then to set a random element to 5 imageviews on my activity.

```
Bitmap[] vector = new Bitmap[52];
int[] randomNumbers = new int[5];

private void createImages() {

        vector [0] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.aphoto);

        vector [1] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anotherphoto);
        vector [2] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.backinbusiness);
        vector [3] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.heythere);
        vector [4] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.whasup);

// and so on
}

private boolean randomNumbersContains(int n, int count) {
        for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            if(randomNumbers[i] == n)
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    private void getRandomNumbers() {
        Random r = new Random();
        int nr;
        randomNumbers[0] = r.nextInt(40) + 1;

        for(int i = 1; i < 5; i ++) {
            do {
                nr = r.nextInt(40) + 1;
            } while (randomNumbersContains(nr, i));

            randomNumbers[i] = nr;
        }
    }

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        getRandomNumbers();

        iv1.setImageBitmap(vector [randomNumbers[0]]);
        iv2.setImageBitmap(vector [randomNumbers[1]]);
        iv3.setImageBitmap(vector [randomNumbers[2]]);
        iv4.setImageBitmap(vector [randomNumbers[3]]);
        iv5.setImageBitmap(vector [randomNumbers[4]]);
    }
```

This is my attempt. Every time the button is clicked, i want another 5 cards from the array.

I don't know why my application crashes. Please help !

Here is the log :

```
07-09 11:34:50.059    8307-8307/com.blabla.bla.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.blabla.bla.app, PID: 8307
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.blabla.bla.app/com.blabla.bla.app.PlayActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #52: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.symplyfyweb.gherghina.oldschoolwesternpoker.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.blabla.bla.app.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 13068012 byte allocation with 1329116 free bytes and 1297KB until OOM
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
            at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:988)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2474)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2381)
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:749)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:135)
            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:131)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.blabla.bla.app.PlayActivity.onCreate(PlayActivity.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-09 11:34:57.310    8307-8318/com.blabla.bla.app I/art﹕ Clamp target GC heap from 64MB to 64MB
```

Comment: A log will be helpful.

Comment: cardVector is your vector array?

Comment: I have put the log too, and yes cardVector is the vector array

Comment: as a general tip: name your package in a useful way and not `com.blabla.bla.app`

Comment: it isn't named like that, but i just put it here like this

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 13068012 byte allocation with 1329116 free bytes and 1297KB until OOM
```

This is what causes your error. This means that you are using to much ram. You could either try to save a downrendered version in your array or to create each `bitmap` just in the moment before you asigning it to your `ImageView`.

Comment: i tried with just one bitmap to asign to a `ImageView` and it also crashes

Comment: Did you store all bitmaps in your array before asigning?

Comment: then try to load only one bitmap before asigning it to the ImageView. If you store all of the Bitmaps in the array all Bitmaps will be loaded into your Ram

Answer (score 0):

Try to recycle Bitmap before set it to ImageView.

```
Bitmap bitmap = vector [randomNumbers[1]];
bitmap.recycle();
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: how exactly works recycle? could you give me an example with three imageviews setting bitmaps?